# How to resolve TypeError in glDeleteTexture()?

Tags: python, typeerror, pyopengl

```
def del_tex(self):
    glDeleteTextures(self.Texture_ID)
```

gives the error

```
TypeError: No array-type handler for type numpy.uintc (value: 1) registered
```

What does it mean by this error and how to resolve it ?

Comment: What is `self.Texture_ID` actually? How is it initialized?

Comment: self.Texture_ID is inititalized with 0 and when texture is loaded it's value is what is returned by glGenTexture()

Comment: I have tried numpy.array as well it also gives OpenGl.Gl.Glerror

Answer (score 1):

PyOpenGL [`glDeleteTextures`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glDeleteTextures.html) deletes a set of textures. The function has 2 arguments. The number of texture objects and the array of textures objects:

```py
texarray = (GLuint*1)(self.Texture_ID)
glDeleteTextures(1, texarray)
```

A list seems to work as well:

```py
glDeleteTextures(1, [self.Texture_ID])
```

---

If an OpenGL error is returned, then the implementation is semantically correct, but the context is wrong. Either the Object is deleted twice or you don't have an valid and current [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) when `glDeleteTextures` is called.
Error 1282 means `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, that indicates that there is no current OpenGL context.

Comment: glDeleteTextures(1, self.Texture_ID) gives TypeError:No array-type handler for type builtins.list (value: [1]) registered', and first one i.e texarray one gives GLError

Comment: OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
 err = 1282,
 baseOperation = glDeleteTextures,
 pyArgs = (
  1,
  <Squares.c_ulong_Array_1 object at 0x000002B30B8DE640>,
 ),
 cArgs = (
  1,
  <Squares.c_ulong_Array_1 object at 0x000002B30B8DE640>,
 ),
 cArguments = (
  1,
  <Squares.c_ulong_Array_1 object at 0x000002B30B8DE640>,
 )
)

Comment: Please read the answer. I have never used  `glDeleteTextures(1, self.Texture_ID)`! It has to be a list! `[self.Texture_ID]`. Try the 1st solution this should be the save one, because it does exactly what is specified at the documentation of [`glDeleteTextures`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glDeleteTextures.html).

Comment: I tried the first one it returns OpenGL.error.GLError (Error is mentioned in my second comment)

Comment: @Utkrisht If an OpenGL error is returned, then the implementation is semantically correct, but the context is wrong. Either the Object is deleted twice or you don't have an valid and current [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) when `glDeleteTextures` is called. Error 1282 means `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, that indicates that there is no OpenGL context